# My computer is lagging diagnosis program?

Tags: windows-7, diagnostic, lag

My computer keeps lagging with my CPU in the 3 or 4% area I am running Windows 7 and have been for a while I suspect my harddrive of failing and thus being the cos. Maybe it is also the motherboard or grafics card... I don't really know how to diagnosis this, since RAM and CPU seem to be at an okay level.

Computer is a self built computer parts:
Motherboard P5QC
CPU Intel E6750 (2,66 Dualcore)
Grafics NVidia 8600GT
OS Windows 7 x64
RAM 3 GB
Harddrive WD5002ABYS
Soundcard Creative X-Fi Platium

Comment: it would help if you provide some actual details in your post. We dont know what computer you are using ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Press Ctrl-Shift-Escape in windows to launch the task manager.  Go to the Performance tab.  See how much virtual/paged memory is being used.  If it's more than about 10% of physical memory, you need to use your memory more wisely (by closing programs you're not using, etc.) or get more memory.  The Processes tab in task manager can help identify memory hogs (click the Memory header to sort by that).
2. Check your hard drive's smart status to see if it's failing.
3. Check your CD ROM drive is working and not hanging on access attempts.  If necessary, disconnect it (when the computer is shutdown) to verify that it's not the issue.
4. Run resmon (start->run->"resmon.exe", return), and check the disk stats etc.
5. Run mmc.exe; add the Performance Monitoring snap-in.  Left click on Console Root->Performance (local)->Monitoring Tools->Performance Monitor.  Right click the white graph area that appears, and add counters.  Check the number of interrupts that are occuring.
6. Run administration tools->Event Viewer, and look for problems.
7. Boot a Linux LiveCD, and see if problems still occur.  If not, it's something in your windows setup, at least, assuming Linux is enabling all the same hardware.  It's worth booting Linux in verbose mode to see if it says anything about blacklisting bad devices etc.

Answer (score 0):

**[Anvir Task Manager Free](http://download.cnet.com/AnVir-Task-Manager-Free/3000-2086_4-10802050.html)**

Full information about processes including command line, DLLs that the program uses, inbound and outbound traffic, disk load, tray icon, performance graph, internet connections, Windows, threads, open files, etc.

- Information about startup programs and services. Integrated database with Descriptions for 100 000+ startup programs, Internet Explorer toolbars and services
- Information about drivers, Internet (TCP/UPD) connections
- Icons in the system tray that indicate:

  1. CPU usage (including a breakdown by application)
  2. Hard drive temperature and disks activity (with per-application info)
  3. Network inbound and outbound traffic
  4. Laptop battery
  5. Memory

Tweaker that gives direct access to hundreds of XP / Vista / Windows 7 settings including settings that cannot be accessed in Windows at all without directly editing the registry

- Click on the title of any application to:

  ```
    o minimize window to system tray and save the taskbar space from clutter
    o make window semi-transparent, save windows transparency
    o pin window 'always on top'
  ```

  -List of recently used folders in Open / Save dialogs
- Drive's free space as a colored horizontal bar in Windows 'My Computer' (Vista style icons on Windows XP)
- Last launched and favorites programs and folders in tray menu

[image]